# Definig pointer side-by-side and type issues

Tags: c++, pointers

So code:

```
int *mine, *yours; // note this declaration 
mine = new int;
yours = mine;
*yours = 8;
delete yours;
*mine = 12;
mine = NULL;
```

Can we define pointers mine, yours like this? And is there anything wrong with this code?

Also,

```
size_t length = 47;
int* plength = &length;
```

Is this code fine?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we define pointers mine, yours like this?

Yes. The compiler would have complained if you couldn't.

> And is there anything wrong with this code?

Yes. Both pointers point to the same object, which you access via `mine` after deleting it via `yours`. Accessing the remnants of a deleted object gives undefined behaviour.

> Is this code fine?

No, and presumably the compiler told you that. `size_t` and `int` are different types, so an `int*` pointer can't be given the address of a `size_t` object (without an evil cast).

Answer (score 0):

> Can we define pointers mine, yours like this? And is there anything wrong with this code?

Absolutely fine. I suggest you can use `typedef` for more clarity when you have pointer declarations of same type in this way,

```
typedef int *p_int;
p_int yours, mine; // Both members are pointers to integer type
```

`size_t` & `int` are of different types, where an integer pointer `plength` can only point to address of integer member but not others.